# Why Won't Columns Ride Up the Page?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to make a mobile responsive layout that has a sidebar that extends down the entire page, one `header`, and underneath this `header`, three columns.

Here is a link to what I am trying to create: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqdvZg)

Here is the code:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
/* media queries */

@media screen and (min-width: 56px) {
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12vh;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
  }
  .col1,
  .col2,
  .col3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .col1 {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .col2 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .col3 {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
/* end of resolution of 56px */

@media screen and (min-width: 864px) {
  .header {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: top left;
  }
  .threecolumns {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  .col1,
  .col2,
  .col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <!-- end of header -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
  </div>
  <!-- end of sidebar -->
  <div class="threecolumns">
    <div class="col1">
      COL1
    </div>
    <!-- end of column1 -->
    <div class="col2">
      COL2
    </div>
    <!-- end of column 2 -->
    <div class="col3">
      col1
    </div>
    <!-- end of column 3 -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of three columns -->
</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

At a resolution of `864px`, I am trying to make the three columns ride up the main container. Right now, they are just hanging out at the bottom of the layout.

**My question:** Why aren't my three columns riding up the container, and what can I do about it?

Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo/error here :

```
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: top left;
  }
```

there is no `float:top left`, so just remove `top`

And you need to add the `box-sizing:border-box`

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
/* media queries */

@media screen and (min-width: 56px) {
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12vh;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
  }
  .col1,
  .col2,
  .col3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .col1 {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .col2 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .col3 {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
/* end of resolution of 56px */

@media screen and (min-width: 864px) {
  .header {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
  }
  .threecolumns {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  .col1,
  .col2,
  .col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <!-- end of header -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
  </div>
  <!-- end of sidebar -->
  <div class="threecolumns">
    <div class="col1">
      COL1
    </div>
    <!-- end of column1 -->
    <div class="col2">
      COL2
    </div>
    <!-- end of column 2 -->
    <div class="col3">
      col1
    </div>
    <!-- end of column 3 -->


  </div>
  <!-- end of three columns -->


</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: I was about to add that, because I added into my code, forget to mention

Comment: Thank you Paulie and Dippas! I really appreciate your help! It means a lot to me!

Comment: @dippas I thought I did it! You didn't receive a notification?

Comment: @Toddsqui you a haver a grey check below the votes .and no I didn't receive. It's not green yet

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a 1px border on everything.

`25% + 75% + 1px = 100% + 1px,` not 100%.